# Keyboard input lag

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I just finished installing Ubuntu 20.04.3 as a dual boot system on my PC.
But now when running Ubuntu, I am having a extremely odd keyboard input delay. As soon as I start typing faster, the input will not be shown at all until I finish typing and then usually takes over a second to fully load the inputted text (depending on the length).

This happens in every  Application I have tried so far.

I have also already tried switching the USB port used for my keyboard, rebooting the system and looking through the setting, but haven't been able to achieve any results.

Interestingly, when I enable the repeat keys and press down on a key, it will instantly be shown as the key is inputted repeatedly no matter the length.

Is this some fault in my system, or is there some sort of input buffer issue that can be fixed otherwise?